# Derivation of Euler-Lagrange equations from Hamilton's and D'Alembert's principle

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, constrained-dynamics

Goldstein's book of *Classical Mechanics* derive the Euler-Lagrange equations from two different principles:

1. *Hamilton's principle* states that

$$\delta S = \delta\int_{t_1}^{t_2}L(q^{i},\dot{q}^{i},t)dt=0,$$

where no conditions on $L(q^{i},\dot{q}^{i},t)$ seem to be required, and from here one can directly obtain Euler-Lagrange equations.

2. *D'Alembert's principle* (in terms of generalized coordinates) states that

$$\sum_{j}\left\lbrace\bigg[\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q}^{j}}\bigg)-\frac{\partial T}{\partial q^{j}}\bigg]-Q_{j}\right\rbrace\delta q^{j}=0,$$

where one needs to consider that the kinetic energy $T$ is a quadratic function of the velocities $\dot{q}^{j}$.

In order to obtain the Euler-Lagrange equations from this principle, one also needs to consider that the generalized force $Q_j$ is derivable from the potential energy function $V$, which must be a function dependent only on the coordinates $q^{j}$. The form of the Lagrangian must be $L=T-V$ in this case.

1. **Is the Hamilton's principle more powerful in the sense that puts no restrictions on the form of the Lagrangian? or there is some missing restriction?**
2. **Is there another way of deriving Euler-Lagrange equations from D'Alembert's principle without restricting the forms of $T$, $V$ and $L$?**

Comment: 1st question: Yes, 2nd question: S'Alembert's principle just provides a justification for Hamilton's principle

Comment: So, the Hamilton's principle does not require that the forces of constraint do no virtual work?

Comment: @bgr95 1) No. The Hamilton principle in that form holds under the conditions of 2) (which is specified in the Goldstein itself).

Comment: but isn't this problem TRIVIAL ? in fact if you put a functional $ L= T-V $ you get the equation of motion so why is it called hamilton's principle if is a trivial conclusion from Euler-Lagrange equation for variational problems ?=

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I) Actually, it's the other way around. Within the context of Newtonian mechanics, the hierarchy is the following from most to least applicable:

1. Newton's laws are always applicable.
2. D'Alembert's principle or Lagrange equations. E.g. sliding friction typically violates D'Alembert's principle.
3. The stationary action principle $S=\int\! dt~L$, with Lagrangian $L=T-U$, and its Euler-Lagrange equations. E.g. a generalized force might not have a generalized potential $U$.

II) In point 3 we have tacitly assumed that the Lagrangian is of the form $$L~=~T-U,\tag{1}$$ 
as is customary. $T$ and $U$ in eq. (1) may be viewed as representing the kinematic and the dynamical side of Newton's 2nd law, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78138/2451) Phys.SE post. The linear structure of eq. (1) also reflects a [categorical-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) composition rules for how to build physical models out of physical subsystems.

There exist strictly speaking exceptions to the form (1), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/50075/2451) Phys.SE post, but these exceptions often lacks categorical-like composition rules, which make them unsuitable for useful model building.

III) For further details and discussions, see e.g. my related Phys.SE answers [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/294688/2451), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/292713/2451), and links therein.

Comment: I don't see clearly that, on the derivation of Euler-Lagrange equations done by Goldstein, Hamilton's principle requires that the generalized force must be derivable from a potential function. He states that the system must be monogenic ($\boldsymbol{F}=-\nabla V$), but I don't see how this actually enters the formulation...

Comment: Sure... the Lagrangian must always be written in terms of the energies (although not necessarily $L=T-V$). If you can't write the force as a potential function it is impossible to have the covariant property of the Lagrangian formulation (something in terms of scalars only). That is the point, right?