# Lagrangian mechanics - constraint forces & virtual work

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, constrained-dynamics

The constraint forces have the dot product 0 ($\textbf C \cdot \textbf x=0$, where $\textbf C$ and $\textbf x$ are vectors, x being the virtual displacement. But the dot product is 0 if $\textbf C$ and $\textbf x$ are perpendicular. So, are the constraint forces always perpendicular to the virtual displacement? Forces such as tension are not always perpendicular to the virtual displacement. Thus, I am asking why forces like tension are not written in the lagrangian equation of lagrangian mechanics? To be more specific, see the example of the Atwood machine.

Answer (score 1):

I) Constraint forces may or may not be perpendicular to the virtual displacements, and may or may not violate [d'Alembert's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle), depending on what they consist of, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82884/2451) Phys.SE post.

II) Concerning [Atwood's machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atwood_machine):

- The tension forces at the two ends of an infinitesimal segment of a massless string cancel each other.
- The internal forces of an unstretchable string and the internal forces of the wheel produce no virtual work, cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23097/2451) Phys.SE post.
- The normal force between the wheel and the string produces no virtual work.
- Sliding friction between the wheel and the string *could* produce  virtual work.

Comment: So tension is not written in the lagrangian equation?Are there other forces besides friction considered as generalized forces? Thanks for the answer