# D'Alembert's principle and equation of motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, constrained-dynamics

Is obtaining proper equation of motion from D'Alembert's principle a mere coincidence or there is some logic behind this?

This is asked because while we are finding the equations in a regime where the displacement is virtual, who guarantees that the obtained equations will do when the displacements are real, too?

Answer (score 1):

1. [D'Alembert's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle) $$ \sum_i (\mathbf{F}^{(a)}_i - \dot{\mathbf{p}}_i) \cdot \delta \mathbf{r}_i~=~0 \tag{1}$$ can be derived from [Newton's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion) and leads to [Lagrange equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics), see e.g. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics,* Chapter 1.
2. Superscript $(a)$ in eq. (1) stands for *applied forces,* cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82884/2451) Phys.SE post.
3. Because the non-applied forces do no [virtual work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_work), we can rewrite (1) as
   $$ \sum_i (\mathbf{F}^{(\rm tot)}_i - \dot{\mathbf{p}}_i) \cdot \delta \mathbf{r}_i~=~0. \tag{2}$$
   On one hand, eq. (2) is clear consistent with Newton's 2nd law
   $$ \dot{\mathbf{p}}_i ~=~ \mathbf{F}^{(\rm tot)}_i. \tag{3}$$ 
   On the other hand, since [virtual displacements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_displacement) probe in all allowed directions (which don't violate the constraints), Newton's 2nd law (3) follows from eq. (2).