# Trouble with grasping D'Alembert's Principle intuitively

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

In Newtonian mechanics we all learned that a mass accelerates when it is under the influence of a nonzero net force.

However, I learned of [D'Alembert's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle) today and it seems to oppose what I learned in Newtonian mechanics. For example, what we (or at least I) considered to be fictitious forces (eg. inertia) is now suddenly relevant. Furthermore, the applied and inertial "forces" are equal when  the object is accelerating!

I am having difficulty in getting an intuitive understanding of how D'Alembert's Principle works and why it doesn't contradict Newton's laws.

Answer (score 1):

Well, [fictitious forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force) are also relevant for Newtonian mechanics in accelerated reference frames (see e.g. [xkcd/123/](http://xkcd.com/123/) for a humorous take), so in that sense [d'Alembert's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle) is no different. At its core d'Alembert's principle is expressing [Newton's 2nd law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion), cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82884/2451) related Phys.SE post and links therein.