# Can Lagrange's equation be used if the virtual work done by constraint forces is not zero?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, work, constrained-dynamics

I'm learning analytical mechanics and was just introduced to d’Alembert’s principle, which I know is only valid when constraint forces' virtual work is zero. My question is, does this restriction also apply to Lagrange's equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to derive the following identity
$$ \sum_{i=1}^N \left(\dot{\bf p}_i-{\bf F}^{(a)}_i\right)\cdot \delta {\bf r}_i 
~=~ \sum_{j=1}^n \underbrace{\left(\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial  T}{\partial \dot{q}^j} -\frac{\partial T}{\partial q^j}-Q^{(a)}_j\right)}_{\text{Lagrange equations}} \delta q^j,\tag{1}$$
cf. Ref. 1. Here the superscript $(a)$ stands for *applied forces,* cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82884/2451) Phys.SE post. Therefore [d'Alembert's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle) holds iff Lagrange equations hold. In other words, if a non-applied force produces virtual work, it violates d'Alembert's principle and Lagrange equations simultaneously.

References:

1. H. Goldstein, *Classical Mechanics;* Chapter 1, eqs. (1.45)+(1.52).

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thank you