# How does derivation of Lagrange equation from d’Alembert principle differ from the derivation of it from principle of least action?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle

Using d’Alembert principle, one doesn't require any assumption like the one made in other case where particle has to follow the path of least action.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, the generalized forces $Q_j$ do need to have (possibly velocity-dependent) potentials for the [stationary action principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action) to work, while this is not necessary for [d'Alembert's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle). See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283238/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8453/2451) related Phys.SE posts.